# Sorting todo.txt lines by its properties

Tags: python, sorting

I'm after a simple code to organize my todo.txt that has Gina Trapani's syntax, that is contexts are preceded by @, projects by +, priorities are marked by (A), (B) etc.. A task can have multiple contexts and projects.

What I would like to achieve is to first sort the lines by context and in the block of a contexts lines should be ordered by projects and lines with priorities comes first in the project.

My code until now:

```
import os
import sys
import re

# Configuration
todo_path = notepad.getCurrentFilename()

def ordered_set(inlist):
    out_list = []
    for val in inlist:
        if not val in out_list:
            out_list.append(val)
    return out_list

class Todo:
    def __init__(self, priority, context, project, due, task, cdate):
        self.__priority = priority
        self.__context = context
        self.__project = project
        self.__due = due
        self.__task = task
        self.__cdate = cdate

    def __len__(self):
     return len(str(re.sub(' +',' ',str(self.__priority) +' '+' '.join(self.__context) + ' ' + ' '.join(self.__project) + ' ' + str(self.__due) + ' ' + str(self.__task) + ' ' + str(self.__cdate) + '\n')))

    def priority(self):
        return self.__priority

    def context(self):
        return self.__context

    def project(self):
        return self.__project

    def due(self):
        return self.__due

    def task(self):
        return self.__task

    def cdate(self):
        return self.__cdate

def BuildTodos():
 global todos
 todo_file = open(todo_path, 'r')
 raw_todos = todo_file.readlines()
 todo_file.close()
 todos = []

 for item in raw_todos:
  item = item.strip("\n")
  todos.append(item)
 console.write("Loaded Todos\n")
 for idx, item in enumerate(todos):  
  words = item.split(' ')  
  priority = [word for word in words if re.match('^\([A-Z]\)',word)]
  context = [word for word in words if word.startswith('@')]  
  project = [word for word in words if word.startswith('+')]  
  due = [word for word in words if word.startswith('due:')]  
  task = [word for word in words if not re.match('^\([A-Z]\)',word) and not word.startswith('@') and not word.startswith('+') and not word.startswith('due:') and not re.match('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}',word)]  
  cdate = [word for word in words if re.match('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}',word)]
  todos[idx] = Todo(priority, context, project, due, task, cdate)
 console.write("Built Todos\n")
 todos.sort(key=lambda t: t.context())
# ----------------
# HELP NEEDED HERE
# sort the lines by context and within the block of contexts lines  should be
# ordered by projects and lines with priorities comes first in the project.
# ---------------- 

def OutTodos():
 for t in todos:
    console.write(re.sub(' +',' ',' '.join(t.priority()) + ' ' + ' '.join(t.context()) + ' ' + ' '.join(t.project()) + ' ' + ' '.join(t.due()) + ' ' + ' '.join(t.task()) + ' ' + ' '.join(t.cdate()) + '\n'))

console.clear()
BuildTodos()
OutTodos()
```

Example todo.txt file, contains utf-8 characters (!):

```
(A) @personal +study +python organize todo.txt áőúíéá
(A) Schedule annual checkup +Health áőúíéá
(B) Outline chapter 5 +Novel @Computer áőúíéá
(C) Add cover sheets @Office +TPSReports áőúíéá
Plan backyard herb garden @Home áőúíéá
Pick up milk @GroceryStore áőúíéá
Research self-publishing services +Novel @Computer áőúíéá
Download Todo.txt mobile app @Phone áőúíéá
```

I'm squeezing my mind on how to construct this sorting so to not end up with a monster. My guess would be to iterate on the todos list and have cascading ifs but not having any experience in sorting/list manipulations in python I'm out for advices.

Comment: Are you trying to assign us a task ? Please show your approach , Also attach sample of text of that file.

Comment: Personally I would have a for loop for each line in the todos then use if statements with regular expressions to pull out any @blah, (A) , +blah etc.

Comment: @anmol_uppal I would appreciate working code as answer but my question is open to advices on what functions, algorithm to use. Didn't asked to do this project of mine, as I see every question assigns a task: look up, think, share from your knowledge. Added to my question code and todo.txt snippet.

Comment: @Rob I have pulled out those meta words and have lists from them: py_collect, co_collect, pt_collect

Comment: Looks like you have the sorting done, but are stuggling how to regenerate the complete words?

Comment: I have sorted the collected properties of todos, I would like to have a todos list that is organized/sorted in the way I described in my question, in the second paragraph.

Comment: "I'm a fresh starter in Python, so" you should maybe start slow and not try something this complicated. How about some tutorials? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: @firelynx I have looked up some tutorials, I didn't think at start that it turns out to be this complicated. I liked the pythonic expressions seen in tutorials so thought this could be done without too much hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using ordered dictionaries is the way forward, that way you get to keep all of the data in each line together and you get to mess around with how you want it printed.

The only issue with the dicts is that they always need a key, where as you don't always supply a context / project / priority. To get around this I added keys of 'zzz' when there were none available (this helps with the sorting and they are removed later).

I also had issues with the .difference you are using as I thought that relied on a set, i.e no repeating data like "to do this I want to" where one of the 'to's would be removed.

Anyway here is the code (Python 2.7):

```
import re
import collections
import sys

fname = "todo.txt"
jobs = {}
myset = set()

#Recursive printing. Also orders the dictionary and removes zzz
def rprint(d):
   a = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
   for key, value in a.iteritems():
      if isinstance(value, dict):
         rprint(value)
      else:
         # check to see if the line is a repitition, this can occour
         # when a line has more than one priority/project/context.
         for line in value:
             if line not in myset:
                 print str(line)
                 myset.add(line)


with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:

      line = line.strip()
      words = line.split(' ')
      priority = [word for word in words if re.match('^\([A-Z]\)',word)]
      context = [word for word in words if word.startswith('@')]
      project = [word for word in words if word.startswith('+')]

      #Need to make sure that there is always a key otherwise it will cause 
      #the dict issues, set key to zzz so that it will appear at the bottom when sorted
      if not priority: priority = ["zzz"]
      if not project:  project = ["zzz"]
      if not context:  context = ["zzz"]

      for i in context:
          for j in project:
              for k in priority:

                  if i not in jobs:
                      jobs[i] = {}
                  if j not in jobs[i]:
                      jobs[i][j] = {}
                  if k not in jobs[i][j]:
                      jobs[i][j][k] = []

                  jobs[i][j][k].append(line)

    rprint(jobs)
```

Comment: Good looking output, but I don't want identation, so to keep the same syntax as in the source, only to organize those lines: first sort the lines by context and in the block of a contexts lines should be ordered by projects and lines with priorities comes first among the project lines.

Comment: @obeliksz I have updated the code to keep the lines exactly as they are in the source. Only ordering the whole lines, not their contents.

Comment: I added a "+Novel Another thing to do @Computer" line to the end of the todo.txt example in the question and when run the script the line "Research self-publishing services +Novel @Computer áőúíéá" didn't get printed.

Comment: @obeliksz Please see the update above. If you are happy please mark my response as answered. Thanks